# Can speaker impedance change over time?

Tags: resistance, speakers

#### Backstory

I've got these old Technics RP-F600 headphones in my closet that I wanted to use. I bought them ages ago (don't remember, probably over 10 years ago), and for the past year or so they've sat on a shelf unused. Before that my wife used them at work and she says that they worked there fine.

#### The problem & what I tried

As I tried them today, the right speaker didn't work. I thought that it would be a simple issue of a faulty wire which I have fixed myself many times before. So I opened them up and got to work with my cheap multi-meter, only to find that all the wires are fine. Even weirder, the right speaker started to produce sound again even though I did nothing. However it is now slightly quieter than the left one. Measuring resistance also confirms this. The left one is a little below 60Ω while the right one is around 80-90Ω and weirdly keeps fluctuating way more than the left one (although I don't know how much of that is simply bad contact or the cheapness of the multi-meter). For reference - the Internet says that the rated impedance of these headphones is 56Ω and the resistance of the wires was around 1.8Ω and didn't fluctuate that much. And anyway I measured both at the plug and at the speaker itself and got the same results in either case.

#### The question

What is going on here? Is the speaker itself dying or is this normal? Can the impedance/resistance of the speaker change as it ages? Is there some known phenomenon that would explain this?

Comment: Bad contact somewhere.

Comment: Your question doesn't make it clear whether you're measuring at the jack plug or at the speaker terminals.

Comment: @Transistor - I just updated that detail right as you commented. :) I measured at both places and got the same results.

Comment: @BrianDrummond - My first thought too, but I just remembered to add the detail that I measured at the speaker itself too, and the results were the same. If there is a bad contact, it then follows it should be inside the speaker? Is that possible?

Comment: Hehe, funny thing is - if I listen to the headphones for a minute or so, _my brain_ adjusts and I cannot hear the difference anymore. :D

Comment: Bad solder joint somewhere, or cracked PCB trace if speaker contains anything that resembles PCB. And speaker impedance is not measured at DC so that explains the measured and rated impedance difference.

Comment: @Justme - no PCB, just a speaker. And I know the difference between resistance and impedance (I was careful when using these terms), however even if I measure resistance the result should be the same for both speakers (even if it is different from the rated impedance).